# Empty subscriber list while channel subscribers count isn't zero

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

### Summary

I'm trying to get a list of channel subscribers, but sometimes I get empty response for specific channels with subscriber count > 0.

### Details

Following [this YouTube Data API documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list),
I'm trying to receive a list of the channel subscriptions, however did received empty list. This is not reproducible for all channels, but it is this channel -- `UCWjFX5qjtUCF4Xr-Z4q0h9w`.
I'm using this command to get the current subscribers:

```
curl \
  'https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatistics&key=XXXXX&mine=true' \ 
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer XXXXXX' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

The API response is:

```json
    {
      "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
      "etag": "XXXXpU",
      "pageInfo": {
        "totalResults": 1,
        "resultsPerPage": 5
      },
      "items": [
        {
          "kind": "youtube#channel",
          "etag": "XXXXXXXaU",
          "id": "UCWjFX5qjtUCF4Xr-Z4q0h9w",
          "snippet": {....},
          "contentDetails": {..},
          "statistics": {
                 ...
            "subscriberCount": "5",
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

and then try to list the subscriptions:

```
curl \
  'https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=snippet,id,subscriberSnippet,contentDetails&key=XXXXXX&mine=true' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer XXXXXX' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

with the JSON response:

```json
    {
      "kind": "youtube#SubscriptionListResponse",
      "etag": "XXXXX3i0vIY",
      "pageInfo": {
        "totalResults": 0,
        "resultsPerPage": 5
      },
      "items": []
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Update the privacy settings in channel settings.

Answer (score 0):

That happens because when invoking the [`Subscriptions.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list) with the request parameter [`mine`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list#mine) set to `true`, you'll obtain a number of channel *to which you -- that channel owner -- have subscribed*:

> [**`mine`**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list#mine) (boolean)
>
> This parameter can only be used in a properly [authorized request](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication). Set this parameter's value to `true` to retrieve a feed of the authenticated user's subscriptions.

But a channel's `statistics.subscriberCount` is counting *the number of other YouTube users that subscribed to* the respective channel:

> [**`statistics.subscriberCount`**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#statistics.subscriberCount) (unsigned long)
>
> The number of subscribers that the channel has. This value is rounded down to three significant figures. Please see the [Revision History](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/revision_history#release_notes_09_10_2019) or the [YouTube Help Center](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6051134) for more details about how subscriber counts are rounded.

For the other way around -- i.e. for a list of channels that are *subscribers of your channel* -- there are two other request parameters: [`myRecentSubscribers`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list#myRecentSubscribers) and [`mySubscribers`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list#mySubscribers).